# Data loss due to unexpected failover of MongoDB replica set

Tags: mongodb, replication, failover, mongodb-replica-set

So I encountered the following issue recently:

I have a 5-member set replica set (priority)

- 1 x primary (2)
- 2 x secondary (0.5)
- 1 x hidden backup (0)
- 1 x arbiter (0)

One of the secondary replicas with 0.5 priority (let's call it **B**) encountered some network issue and had intermittent connectivity with the rest of the replica set. However, despite having staler data and a lower priority than the existing primary (let's call it **A**) it assumed primary role:

> [ReplicationExecutor] VoteRequester: Got no vote from xxx because: candidate's data is staler than mine, resp:{ term: 29, voteGranted: false, reason: "candidate's data is staler than mine", ok: 1.0 }
>
> [ReplicationExecutor] election succeeded, assuming primary role in term 29
>
> [ReplicationExecutor] transition to PRIMARY

And for **A**, despite not having any connection issues with the rest of the replica set:

> [ReplicationExecutor] stepping down from primary, because a new term has begun: 29

So **Question 1** is, how could this have been possible given the circumstances?

Moving on, **A** (now a secondary) began rolling back data:

> [rsBackgroundSync] Starting rollback due to OplogStartMissing: our last op time fetched: (term: 28, timestamp: xxx). source's GTE: (term: 29, timestamp: xxx) hashes: (xxx/xxx)
>
> [rsBackgroundSync] beginning rollback
>
> [rsBackgroundSync] rollback 0
>
> [ReplicationExecutor] transition to ROLLBACK

This caused data which was written to be removed. So **Question 2 is:** How does an OplogStart go missing?

Last but not least, **Question 3**, how can this be prevented?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using version 3.2.x and protocolVersion=1 (you can check it with rs.conf() -command)? Because there is "bug" on voting.
You can prevent this bug by (choose one or both):

- change protocolVersion to 0. 
  cfg = rs.conf();
  cfg.protocolVersion=0;
  rs.reconfig(cfg);
- change all priorities to same value

EDIT:
These are tickets what explain.. More or less..
[Ticket 1](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-22502)
[Ticket 2](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-23663)

Comment: `3.2.4` and `protocolVersion: 1`!

Comment: This issue right? https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-18453. I see this answers Questions 2 and 3... but how about Question 1?